# Exchange EWS SearchMailboxes invalid child element error

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a strange error. When i try to do a SearchMailboxes, I get this error:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The request "://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" has invalid child element 'ExtendedAttributes'

The problem is that i get this error in some pc's. With fiddler I could see that my pc sends a request without the node [ExtendedAttributes and it works](http://s17.postimg.org/isjyo2x1b/Untitled2.png).

[This is the ExtendedAttributes node that produces the error.](http://s7.postimg.org/elu453sff/Untitled2.png)

The code:

```
        List<MailboxSearchScope> scopeList = new List<MailboxSearchScope>();
        foreach (SearchableMailbox mb in searchableMailboxes)
        {
            MailboxSearchScope scope = new MailboxSearchScope(mb.ReferenceId, MailboxSearchLocation.All);
            scopeList.Add(scope);
        }

        MailboxQuery query = new MailboxQuery(searchQuery, scopeList.ToArray());

        MailboxQuery[] mbQueryList = new MailboxQuery[] { query };
        SearchMailboxesParameters p = new SearchMailboxesParameters
        {
            SearchQueries = mbQueryList,
            ResultType = SearchResultType.PreviewOnly
        };

        ServiceResponseCollection<SearchMailboxesResponse> res = _service.SearchMailboxes(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExtendedAttributes` is a new element that was introduced in Exchange 2013 SP1 and is intended for internal use only.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn627392(v=exchg.150).aspx

I don't see in your code where you are trying to use this element so I would suggest that you specify `ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013` when you are instantiating your ExchangeService object.

Comment: I already put "ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013" on the ExchangeService constructor. ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")); .    Another problem is that in my pc I don't need to specify the exchange version, but in the other pc if I don't specify the version it throws an exception.

The same code!

I'm using v15.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices and Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using? Do both machines access the same mailbox on the same server? You may also want to download the latest version of the EWS Managed API (version 15.00.0847.032) from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022

Comment: Is an Exchange 2013. Same mailbox, same server. I have the lastest version of dlls. If I use the EWS with ExchangeServiceBinding I have the same error. So, I think that dlls is not the problem.

Comment: Something has to be different between these two machines to cause different responses. What happens when you send your EWS request from a different client, like [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/)? Have you tried any of the [tracing functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) in the EWS Managed API? I'm just looking for additional information that may help us track down this issue for you.

Comment: Sorry! I'm wrong, the problem is with the sdk dlls! I reinstalled it again but it does not work. Now, I'm using the EWS and works fine.